# Types of attractors

Tags: chaos-theory

In studying dynamical systems and chaos theory, one usually gets across a classification that says that [attractors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor) can be of four basic types:

-fixed point (equilibrium)

-cyclic (periodic)

-torus (quasiperiodic)

-strange (chaotic)

This is usually an informal statement, but can we give a proof that this classification is complete, that is there is no fifth type of attractor?

Note: If this seems too hard to answer in general, let's stay in phase space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to not overcomplicate.

Comment: There is Poincare-Bendixson Theorem but it doesn^t apply for $n>2$. So staying in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ also seems overcomplicated.

Comment: @i.ozturk What about $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Comment: also can't we do proof by contradiction?

Comment: I don't know any other theorem and I don't know how you can do it sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not another types but anothe clasiifications :

- based on the [simplicity of finding basin of attraction in the phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_oscillation)
- based on the speed of attraction ( superattracting, attracting, [weakly attracting](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Critical_orbit_3d.png))

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Another one if I may quickly add is known as a strange nonchaotic attractor (SNA). 
See: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_nonchaotic_attractor" 
and references therein for starters.